# NotificationCompat.Builder does not set Large and small icon

Tags: android, notifications

This is how I am setting the icons. However both the icons are not set. The default Android icon is shown for the large icon. How do I solve this?

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(context)
                .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_alarm_on_white_24dp)
                .setContentTitle(context.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setTicker(mTitle)
                .setContentText(mTitle)
                .setContentIntent(mClick)
                .setAutoCancel(true)
                .setOnlyAlertOnce(true);
```

Comment: Are you using NotificationCompat V4 or V7 package?

Comment: I am using v7 package

Comment: So use V4 package your problem will be resolve

Comment: Have you resolve your problem?